# find common rows of matching column from two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with a column values mostly matching with each other.

How can I find row that are matching in common to that column.

Here is my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72af4/5)

It is showing Error at B

Comment: What is that Error?

Comment: If all you are selecting is the count, then why are you aliasing the table names?

Answer (score 1):

I think JOIN will work, please try below:

```
SELECT A.ProductName 
FROM ForgeRock AS A 
JOIN ForgeRock1 AS B ON A.ProductName = B.ProductName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ON is missing

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ForgeRock  A JOIN ForgeRock1  B
on A.ProductName = B.Productname
```